# How to run a shell command without opening a CMD window in VB6

Tags: windows, vba, vb6, batch-file

the following code is part from my VB6 program

I used shell command  in the VB in order to execute the pscp.exe with the flags and arguments

my problem is , when VB run the line:

```
      Shell strCommand, 1
```

its also open the CMD window for 2-4 seconds (CMD popup window)

my question - is it possible to run the "Shell strCommand, 1"  in way that CMD window will not opened?

I mean - I not want to see any CMD popup window when I run VB application

```
  Const cstrSftp As String = "D:\pscp.exe"
  Dim strCommand As String
  Dim pUser As String
  Dim pPass As String
  Dim pHost As String
  Dim pFile As String
  Dim pRemotePath As String
  pUser = "root"
  pPass = "pass123"
  pHost = "110.218.201.15"
  pFile = """D:\scan_ip.ksh""" 
  pRemotePath = "/var/tmp"

  strCommand = cstrSftp & " -sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & " " & pHost & ":" & pRemotePath & " " & pFile


  Shell strCommand, 1
```

Comment: By not explicitly telling it to be shown :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use hidden focus:

```
Shell strCommand, vbHide
```

or

```
Shell strCommand, 0
```

For other focus types look [Here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/9/shell-and-shellexecute-function/)
or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087%28v=VS.60%29.aspx (thanks to MarkJ for the link)

Comment: +1 The arguments are also documented in the manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087(v=VS.60).aspx