# How to embed the window of another application in my application

Tags: vb6, exe, ole, embedding

I am making an app in Visual Basic 6.0  which includes feed from cctv camera. The cctv system runs as an `.exe` application but it doesn't comes with `.dll` file that can be embedded.

How to "embed" that window in my VB form?

I know about `Shell()` which runs application in different window, but I want it to embed completely in my form not in another window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably, you were trying to embed the window rather than the exe file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed it as a resource in your exefile. But you have to extract it and run it. You can run it hidden as prev poster noted.

How to do that? Download ResHacker to embed the resource.

Here's a sample that includes vb6 source code for a self extracting installer. Don't install it as what it installs doesn't work on post win 2000 versions. The installer part does work any version.

http://mvps.org/serenitymacros/images/webview.zip

Answer (score 1):

Run the exe and take the hwnd to change its parent to your app form.

Comment: But be careful to shut it down, or unparent it again when your application exits. Getting rid of the frame and the rest of the windows is pretty much impossibly though.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to show the command prompt you can have a look at the following post [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735463/how-to-run-a-shell-command-without-opening-a-cmd-window-in-vb6)

Comment: I don't think you got my question!