# Execute batch file from a macro button

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have a batch file in a specific location. This batch file renames the images in the same location. I just need to run this batch file through macro button from excel. 
Also, is it possible to key in the PREFIX value as user input.I appreciate if anyone can provide macro for this.

```
@echo off
SET COUNT=1
SET PREFIX=40054578_Image
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.jpg') DO (call :renum "%%G")
GOTO :eof

:renum
ren %1 %PREFIX%-%count%.jpg
set /a count+=1
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Maybe you should check this question and adapt it to your specific situation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8735463/6671476

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, copy this code at the top of your module:

```
Private Declare Function OpenProcess _
    Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
     ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
     ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CloseHandle _
    Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject _
    Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hHandle As Long, _
     ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
```

---

Now copy the macro below that code and change the path to match your bat file name and directory location:

```
Sub runBatch()
    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\yourUserName\Desktop\myBatchFile.bat"  '<-- change this

    'Ask user for prefix
    Dim prefix As String
    prefix = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Prefix: ", Title:="Prefix", Default:="Enter Prefix Here")

    'Make sure something was entered
    If prefix = vbNullString Or prefix = "Enter Prefix Here" Then Exit Sub

    'Run bat file
    procID = Shell(path & " " & prefix, vbNormalFocus)

    If procID = 0 Then
         'Handle Error, Shell Didn't Work
    Else
         hProcess = OpenProcess(&H100000, True, procID)
         WaitForSingleObject hProcess, -1
         CloseHandle hProcess
    End If
End Sub
```

---

This macro prompts the user to input a prefix into a text box and then passes the value to the batch file.  Now change your batch file to use the passed parameter by setting the prefix to `%1` (means the first parameter passed to batch file):

```
SET PREFIX=%1
```

---

If you want to see the value passed into the batch file, add an ECHO and pause to the batch file so the console doesn't dismiss right away.

```
@echo off
ECHO Prefix passed in: %1
pause
```

Comment: Hi Runner, Thanks. It asks for user input and then a dos prompt window flashes and there it says no file found. Nothing happens. When i checked the folder, the prefix parameter has not passed and renaming never happened. Any idea please.

Comment: If the path and file name is not correct in the VBA to your batch file you will see 'File not found' error.  Make sure your path... C:\... is correct.

Comment: Try my workbook, download these two files: [file1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8oK36klPLEWa21WbEVPb1RNVWc), [file2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8oK36klPLEWSDdEZnA5YURlZWs) and put them in this new folder `C:\Temp\excel` Open the Excel workbook and run the macro via button.